# Rails ajax fileupload (remotipart)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I constructed a webservice that uses the remotipart gem to uplad files to the server. The form used to transmit the data is a ajax form (remote => true). Everything works just fine, the file gets saved etc.

The problem however is, that the jquery library triggers the ajax:error event as a response to the totally fine answer of the server (a `200 OK` or `201`) when the object is updated. The controller answers with a format.json

```
  format.json { render json: @author, status: :created, location: @author }
```

The javascript, responsible for evaluating the response follows the documentation

```
 .bind("ajax:error", function (xhr, status, error ...
```

The answer in the browser is a `200`, even the statuscode in the jQuery object is `200`. the type however is an `ajax:error`. Does anyone know how this can happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It is resolved when adding the (required) i-frame transport library. That one's on me.

```
//= require jquery.iframe-transport
```

Comment: this didn't fix the issue for me :/